# Overwrite object in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This should be simple but it is surprisingly difficult and extremely frustrating.  I am trying to overwrite an 'Object' field in mongodb with a new Object that the user creates in my client webpage.  I have validated that all other fields I am passing to the update operation are in fact being updated, with the exception of the javascript object.  Instead of it updating with the object I am passing (While I validated is being populated with the object I am passing through), it just updates it back to {} instead of whats being passed:

```
{ nodes:[ { w: 120, h: 80,type: 'InHive',left: 184,top: 90,text: 'item',query: 'hey',name: 'sample',id: '7686132d-6fcf-4a3b-baa2-b1c628e0b2d6' } ], edges: [], ports: [],groups: [] }
```

When I attempt to update the data field outside of the meteor method, directly from the mongo console interface, it overwrites that field successfully with the javascript object.  What am I doing wrong here, because I cant for the life of me figure this one out?

Server Method

```
    'updateOneWorkflow': function(id, field, object) {
    this.unblock;
    if (Meteor.userId()) {
        var _username = Meteor.user().username;
        MYCOLLECTION.update({
            _id: id
        }, {
            $set: {
                [field]: object, //this just gets reset back to {} whenever this update method is called
                "metadata.last_modified_dt": new Date(), //this gets updated
                "metadata.modified_by": Meteor.userId(), //this gets updated
                'metadata.modified_by_username': _username //This gets updated
            }
        });
    } else {
        throw new Meteor.Error(403, "You are not authorized to perform this function");
    }
}
```

Client Call:

```
var _jsonformat = toolkit.exportData();
        var currentid = Session.get('rulesRowClicked')._id;
        console.log(_jsonformat);
        Meteor.call('updateOneWorkflow' , currentid, 'data', _jsonformat, function(err, res){
            if(err){
                toastr.error('Failed to save result ' + err);
            }
            else{
                toastr.success('Saved workflow');
            }
        });
```

Comment: what are the values/types of 'field' and 'object' before the update statement? can you show us what you get if you run console.log(field) / console.log(object)?

Comment: If you look at the client code, it shows what is being passed to the method above.  Field is 'data' and the console log on both the server and the client do show the JSON object being populated along with the field value.

Comment: Try `console.log` the `object` var inside your method in server

Comment: the console log is included in the question { nodes:[ { w: 120, h: 80,type: 'InHive',left: 184,top: 90,text: 'item',query: 'hey',name: 'sample',id: '7686132d-6fcf-4a3b-baa2-b1c628e0b2d6' } ], edges: [], ports: [],groups: [] }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was crazier than I expected.  If you are using Meteorjs and you are using the Aldeed Schema 2 collection framework, it seems to completely ignore updates/inserts of json objects even if you set the field type to Object, unless you set up the exact same schema as the object (including nested array objects) and attach it to your collection.  Dumbest thing Ive ever seen, no idea why nothing warns you of this.  I removed the schema attachment and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is stemming from this line: `[field]: object`. I don't believe that's a proper method of dynamically accessing an object's field. Instead, try to dynamically update the field as so:

```
'updateOneWorkflow': function(id, field, object) {
    this.unblock;
    if (Meteor.userId()) {
        var _username = Meteor.user().username;
        var newObj = {
            "metadata": {
                "last_modified_dt": new Date(),
                "modified_by": Meteor.userId(),
                "modified_by_username": _username
            }
        };
        newObj[field] = object;
        MYCOLLECTION.update({
            _id: id
        }, {
            $set: newObj
        });
    } else {
        throw new Meteor.Error(403, "You are not authorized to perform this function");
    }
}
```

Comment: same results unfortunately, seems to only be updating the 3 metadata columns but not the actual data object with the object passed to the function.  Still shows as {}

Comment: @user2100493 can you console log on the server just to be sure it's getting to the server ok?

Comment: sure, here is the output: {
 metadata: {
  last_modified_dt: "Wed Jan 25 2017 19: 33: 01 GMT - 0500(EST)",
  modified_by: 't4hcAugBkr2ax6E3G',
  modified_by_username: 'ngaadmin'
 },
 data: {
  nodes: [
   [Object]
  ],
  edges: [],
  ports: [],
  groups: []
 }
}

Comment: @user2100493, so your `object` already has a key for the metadata? Not that it really matters. I'm kind of stumped, sorry!

Comment: no, that's just the complete object per your code.  it includes both the metadata and object in one object per your example.