# MongoDB Update Method Not Working

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Hoping someone out there could tell me where I am going wrong with this update method:

```js
  changeTaskDetails: function(singleID,detailsTarget){
    TaskDetails.update({
      _id: singleID,
    }, {
      $set:{
        projectType: detailsTarget,
      }
    });
    console.log(singleID);
  },
```

Here is the event:

```js
  'submit #editTaskDetails'(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var id = FlowRouter.getParam('taskId');
    const singleDetailsUpdate = Tasks.findOne({_id:id});

    const singleID = singleDetailsUpdate._id;
    const target = event.target;
    const facilityTarget = target.facilityName.value;
    const inspectorTargetName = target.detailsinspector.value;
    const inspectorIdTarget = target.inspectorid.value;
    const detailsTarget = target.detailstype.value;
    const dateTarget = target.TaskDate.value;

    console.log(singleID)
    Meteor.call("changeTaskDetails", singleID,detailsTarget);
  },
```

I can get the 2 props to log...but its not updating the DB. No errors in either console.

Comment: If you log the detailsTarget value on changeTaskDetails, what do you get?

Comment: Are you using the Aldeed Schema 2 collection framework? Another user had a similar problem with that package, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41842750/overwrite-object-in-mongodb/41859259#comment70912404_41859259)

Comment: I have logged the detailsTarget value on both client and server, and both seem to log just fine. This field is a String. I have also tried logging a few other forms fields from the form and they log alright as-well. 

Yes I am using the collection2 framework. I should mention that I have many other inserts, and remove methods....these seem to work just fine. This is my first update method.

Comment: @JoethaCoder, I can't find anything wrong with your code. It looks great. Given that another user had issues with the update function and the collection2 framework, would it be difficult for you to try and remove it?

Comment: @Adam Thanks for the suggestion. I totally removed the Schema, Schema Attachment, and all validation references....but still came up with the same issue. No errors, and everything logs.

Comment: Strange, I really can't find anything wrong with the code. I think the update function returns the # of records updated (i.e. `var numUpdated = TaskDetails.update(...`). If it finds a records and updates it, numUpdated should equal to 1. Can you try the above and log numUpdated? It might help point us in the right direction.

Comment: can you attach a callback to your update() call and see if there's an error?

Comment: I did try this and it returned 0. HOWEVER I solved the issue. Will answer my own question below....thanks EVERYONE for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I had a session variable controlling when you could (or could not) see the update form. For one reason or another the form crapped out when inside of this area. When I removed the session, and added the form to the main template...it worked!